# Angular not sending traces to OTel collector

Tags: angular, open-telemetry

I have a OTel collector using this: https://hub.docker.com/r/jaegertracing/opentelemetry-all-in-one/

Running this with .NET backend works fine, so I'm sure the OTel is set up correctly. Now I want to add Angular frontend traces.

In my app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    OpenTelemetryInterceptorModule.forRoot({
      commonConfig: {
        console: true,
        production: false,
        serviceName: 'Poc Client',
        probabilitySampler: '1'
      },
      otelcolConfig: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4317'
      },
    }),
    OtelColExporterModule,
    ConsoleSpanExporterModule,
    CompositePropagatorModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I can see the trace's ID generated in Angular gets propagated to my .NET backend because the trace in .NET contained the trace ID in Angular as its parent ID.

My problem now is that the traces is not showing in Jaeger's UI. So where am I doing this wrong? I've tried different combination of URL `http://127.0.0.1:4317`, `http://127.0.0.1:4317/v1/traces`, changing the 127.0.0.1 to localhost, nothing works. How do I send the traces from Angular to the collector?

Comment: You need to configure the CORS settings in OTLP HTTP receiver. You may find this helpful https://signoz.io/blog/opentelemetry-angular/, https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/receiver/otlpreceiver#cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing

Comment: I'm not using Signoz though, so why should I? And also if there is a CORS errors, it should appear in the DevTool, but it's not.

Comment: I was just giving some pointers that might help you fix the issue. The most likely reason is CORS and you didn't mention you enabled that configuration. So I thought that could be the reason.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If so can you provide the answer here?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, cors issues with jaeger collector